# getting error while executing hdfs namenode -format(Hadoop)

Tags: java, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

```
hadoop1@kdblue:~$ hdfs namenode -format
```

its giving this error!

/home/hadoop1/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /opt/jdk1.7.0_95//bin/java: No such file or directory

this is my set path varibles

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Comment: is your JAVA_HOME set ??

Comment: yes!!@DeepanRam

Comment: Can you try :-

hdfs namenode -format -force

Comment: Giving the same error

Comment: Check the hadoop.env.sh, whether JAVA_HOME is set or not ?

Comment: i set JAVA_HOME                                                                                        # The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_95/@DeepanRam

Comment: Can you post the output of  `ls $JAVA_HOME/bin/java`?

Comment: ls: cannot access /bin/java: No such file or directory@franklinsijo

Comment: Check whether the dir structure exists or not /opt/jdk1.7.0_95/bin/java ?

Comment: ls: cannot access /opt/jdk1.7.0_95/bin/java: No such file or directory@franklinsijo

Comment: you need to specify the exact location where you have installed the java for the JAVA_HOME and its good to include that in the .bashrc file.

Comment: hadoop1@kdblue:~$ java -version
_java version "1.7.0_95"_
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)@franklinsijo

Comment: i already added in .bashrc@DeepanRam

Comment: Not the good way : -  `alternatives --display java`

Displays the location of the java .

Comment: its contain 2 jdks   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64 and /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64@franklinsijo

Comment: Better to remove the java-6-openjdk-amd64 and only keep 1.7 version.
While upgrading from 1.6 to 1.7 , its a good practice to remove the older version.

Comment: @kdblue Change the `JAVA_HOME` value to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`.

Comment: @franklinsijo thanks bro its work !!!!!! :)

Comment: @DeepanRam thanks !!!! :)